# Why does the time.sleep work even before the window (tkinter) opens?

Tags: python, tkinter, time

Why does the `time.sleep()` work before the window of `tkinter` opens?

Code:

```
import tkinter
import time
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Holst")


holst = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = 450, height = 450, bg = "white")
holst.place(x = 25, y = 25)

x = 30
y = 50
d = 30

circle = holst.create_oval(x, y, x+d, y+d, fill = "red")
time.sleep(2)
holst.move(circle, 50, 40)
```

Comment: Please don't add junk characters to work around site rules.

Comment: It is because `time.sleep()` is in the main block, where the code gets executed first.

Answer (score 0):

You asked that why is `time.sleep()` is called before the windows loads
because you hopefully called the `window.mainloop()` at the last of the code which loads the window and keep maintain the tkinter window

The `time.sleep()` function code executes before the `window.mainloop()` function so it was stop the execution and sleeps before the window could load

A nice approach will be to call the `time.sleep()` in a `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The Tk instance requires you to run it's mainloop function in order to take control of the main process thread.

Your code is calling time.sleep() on the main process thread, which blocks the GUI from doing anything. If you want to be able to do things with the GUI while waiting (such as drawing the window, moving it around, or drawing other things to it) then you would need to extend Tk to have the UI handle the callback using self.after()

Here's a simple example of how you would extend the Tk class to achieve what you want.

```
import tkinter

class TkInstance(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)

        #Set up the UI here
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self, width = 450, height = 450, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.place(x = 25, y = 25) #Draw the canvas widget

        #Tell the UI to call the MoveCircle function after 2 seconds
        self.after(2000, self.MoveCircle) #in ms

    def MoveCircle(self):
        x = 30
        y = 50
        d = 30
        circle = self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+d, y+d, fill = "red")
        self.canvas.move(circle, 50, 40) #Draw the circle

#Main entrance point
if __name__ == "__main__": #good practice with tkinter to check this
    instance = TkInstance()
    instance.mainloop()
```